# How can i declare array indexing value in an array using JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have initiated an array inside the function like

```
function initColor(r) { 

 r[0].color = "#007FFF", r[1].color = "#A142FF", r[2].color = "#FF85C2", r[3].color = "#FFA142", r[4].color = "#FF4242";

    for (var o = 5; o < r.length; o++) {
        var t = d3.color(r[o % 4 + 1].color);
        r[o].color = t.brighter(1.5).toString()
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to call the function initColor() I'm getting error like

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

What was a mistake in my code?

Comment: `r` must be already populated with objects for that code to work, sounds like it isn't.

Comment: can you give an example @CertainPerformance

Comment: replace `r[0].color` with `(r[0] = r[0] || {}).color`

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri your original array (r) is either empty or does not exist at all, that's it.

Comment: @Siddharthaesunuri for example, `[{}, {}]` would be an array with two empty objects. You can't add or change properties of an element of the array if there is no element in the array.

Comment: You can also give your function default values like so `function initColor(r = [{ color: "#000000" }, { color: "#000000" }, { color: "#000000" }])` This will help if you really need the initial color but don’t have an initial array

Answer (score 1):

As far as i have understood and tested it now, i think there are several mistakes beeing made here.

first of all, as seen in the comments, your array must contain objects. Otherwise you can not change the color property (or set it).

```
r[0].color = "#007FFF", r[1].color = "#A142FF", r[2].color = "#FF85C2", r[3].color = "#FFA142", r[4].color = "#FF4242";
```

here, you try to set/change the color property of the first 5 elements in the given array. If only ONE of these elements is missing (or not of type object), the error you mentioned will be thrown.

But there is another mistake in your code:

```
for (var o = 5; o < r.length; o++) {
    var t = d3.color(r[o % 4 + 1].color);
    r[o].color = t.brighter(1.5).toString()
}
```

the variable o is initiallized with 5. As you only try to set the color of the first 5 elements in the array, i guess you know, at the time of calling this function, that your array only contains 5 elements.

o will alwasy be equal to r.length then and thus, the loop will never be used.